# Algebraic cusp-planar curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Quote from Wikipedia:"The plane curve cusps are all diffeomorphic to one of the following forms:

$x^2 − y^{2k+1} = 0$, where $k ≥ 1$ is an integer."

1)Can one provide a reference for this?

2)Consider the curve $C=\{(x,e^{-\frac{1}{x}}):x\in[0,1]\}\cup\{(x,-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}):x\in[0,1]\}$ that has a cusp point at the origin.How is this curve diffeomorphic to one from (1)

3)Is there such notion as algebraic cusp?vs non-algebraic cusp?